Handling of user-provided API keys in a client-side app (no server). Secure?
I'd like to create a simple JavaScript app that asks a user for their API key from a third-party service and makes it easier to use the service with a better GUI. There will be no server-side code on my side, opensource, hosted on GitHub. So, the question is:

Is it secure at all, or should I forget it? How could the key be leaked?
Can you preserve the API key between sessions? Perhaps using a browser-based password manager?

I'm considering using a password input and generating custom request() function that scopes the provided API key during the session:
function createRequest(apiKey) {
    const apiUrl = 'https://example.com/data';
    return function request() {
        fetch(apiUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({data: 'example'})
        })
        .then(response => ...)
    }
}


Server-side logic could be better for something like this - your users would have their credentials encrypted in your DB. When they log into your system, you would retrieve the API key, and then use it as you normally would. Or, assuming you control the API, you could pipe your users' request through your server, pass it on to your API, and the API would verify both the key and additional parameters your server would send (for example, you could hardcode the API to accept a specific key only from a specific IP).

@FiddlingAway Storing users’ credentials in a reversible form is the last thing you want to do, that’s a giant responsibility! If your server gets compromised, 3rd party accounts of all your users are compromised.

As long as credentials just stay in the browser, it should be fine. They never leave the user’s machine, so the responsibility lies entirely with the user to keep them safe. Storing them in local storage or such compromises that somewhat; I’d leave that up to the user to store them securely in a password manager with autofill capability.
